# Windows Phone App rose an exception when resuming

Tags: windows-phone-7, exception, tombstoning

I'm developing a Windows Phone App.
I submitted it to Microsoft and they sent me back a file describing an error that occurs when resuming the app (it's relative to the 5.2 Performance and Resource Management, point 5.2.3).

To reproduce the error, I run the app, I start on the start button to go to the "desktop" and click on the "Back" button.
After that, the visual studio highlights in yellow the `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();` line in this code

```
// Code to execute on Unhandled Exceptions
        private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        { 
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            }
        }
```

With the stacktrace, I found that the last called method was `CallApplicationUEHandler`.

So, is it a known exception? Did I forget to handle some exceptions?

Here are the last three lines of output just above the the call of CallApplicationUEHandler:

```
first chance exception 'System.ArgumentNullException' in Microsoft.Phone.Controls.dll
first chance exception 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Windows.dll
first chance exception 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Windows.dll
```

The constructors:

For the MainPage:

```
public MainPage()
        {
            journal.Debug(string.Format("Entrée méthode {0}", new StackTrace().GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name));
            InitializeComponent();

            Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded);
        }



private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mainVM = new MainViewModel();
        DataContext = mainVM;
    }
```

For the App:

```
public App()
        {
            // Global handler for uncaught exceptions. 
            // Note that exceptions thrown by ApplicationBarItem.Click will not get caught here.
            UnhandledException += Application_UnhandledException;

            // Standard Silverlight initialization
            InitializeComponent();

            // Phone- {2} -specific initialization
            InitializePhoneApplication();
        }

private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
           if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            }
        }
```

Comment: `CallApplicationUEHandler` was the top thing because that's what set off the chain of events to your unhandled exception handler.  What is the *rest* of the stack trace?  the thing right below that on the stack would give us more information to help you.  Is there an `InnerException` with more details?

Comment: @John Gardner: I have nothing below. But the last three debug lines contain first chance exceptions. I edited the post to show them.

Comment: Can you confirm that the app has finished fully loading before you first navigate away?

Comment: I have the eccept same error massages. Driving me nuts. In my case the app will sometimes not start.

Answer (score 1):

By the fact `Application_UnhandledException` is being called it's fairly likely you're not handling an exception somewhere.

Debug this by looking at the page constructor of the page being loaded and also the `OnNavigatedTo` event handler, if you have one.

At the app level, look at what you're doing in `Application_Activated`.

Comment: I'm doing nothing in the Application_Activated method.

Comment: @Zakaria and whst about the constructor or OnNavigatedTo events?

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in Try-Catch Block. I was also facing such problem, but then handled by Exception Handling Method.

```
try
 {

   // your code

 }

catch (Exception ex)
 {

   throw (ex);
 }
```